# How to get a number from a TextView that also has Strings

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have two `TextView`'s that display averages from couple of EditText boxes and display them as **"My Avg: 245"** and the other `Textview` has **"My Avg: 145"**. I'm calculating the avg in these two `TextView`'s on a button click and setting the text of the button to the answer. How do I get only the number from both the text view? Because when call `Double.parseDouble()` on the TextView, I'm getting an error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
[image]

Comment: what is the error ? past it here, and you to display the result average ?.. if you can show us the code also to help you

Comment: use regex for extracting number from string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by calculating the average in the textview? wherever you do that calculation you should be able to access the values, trying to parse the value from the textview is not a very good practice.

Share your code and the error you are getting, i'm guessing that you are trying to parse the value with the complete string of the textview and, as you can imagine, is not possible to get the Double value from a String.

If the String `My avg:` never changes, then you split this string from the ":" symbol and trim the value.

```
String text = "My avg: 245";

String numberString = text.split(":")[1];
Double number = Double.parseDouble(numberString);

System.out.println(number);
```

the output is:

```
245.0
```

I insist that you should not this approach, if the text changes by any reason, your app will break.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I didn't know why I trying to get the avg from the TextView. Now I just get the values from the EditText and calculating from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Get String from all EditText and extract number from string using Regex. Check below example:

```
String str = "My Avg: 145";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher( str );

if( m.find() ){
    String i=m.group(); 
    System.out.println( "-->>" + i);
}
```

Here

```
\d means one digit 
\d+ means one or more digits
() means capture that group
```

This regrx will give you first group of digits in your string. You can parse `i` using `double.parse();`

Comment: the only issue with this is if for any reason they add another number in the textview( lets say '1.- Average:565'), we fall back to the same issue i mentioned, which renders this solutions as good as the string split.

Comment: This would work as @LuisDurazo stated but my avg in the TextView changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can get number from text view like following :

```
String textView = tv.getText().toString();

if (!textView.equals("") && !textView.equals(......)) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(textView);//extract number from text view  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly call `Double#parseDouble` on a `String` as it might throw `NumberFormatException` if its not a number.

So, you will have to get the number out of it first. You can do it by using `String#split`.

Get the String using the `TextView#getText()`

The split the text using,

```
String[] val =  textViewText.split(":");
```

This will return an array, you can then call `Double.parseDouble`,

```
double num = Double.parseDouble(val[1].trim());
```